# Eval string in code (interpolation)

Tags: vb.net

Assuming the following...

```
Dim x as string = "hello"

dim y as string = "world"

dim z as string = "{x} {y}"  'Note: no $ (not interpolation )
```

I would like to call a method that when passing z would return "hello world"

Note: z can have 0 or more {} and should be evaluated based on the scope of the caller

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

String interpolation is available in VB.NET 14. To interpolate a string, do the following...

```
Dim x as string = "hello"
Dim y as string = "world"

Dim z = $"{x} {y}"
```

This is shorthand for...

```
dim z = String.Format({0}{1}, x,y)
```

For more information on VB.NET 14, see [14 Top Improvements in Visual Basic 14](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn890368.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It is, by using `String.Format`, if you use numbers instead of letters in your placeholders:

```
Dim x As String = "hello"
Dim y As String = "world"
Dim z As String = "{0} {1}"
Dim output As String = String.Format(z, x, y)
```

Since any string can be passed to `String.Format` as the format string, even if it's dynamic, and since the rest of the parameters are a param array, you could even do something like this (though it's a needless wrapper around the already usable method):

```
Public Function MyFormat(format As String, values() As Object) As String
    Return String.Format(format, values)
End Function
```

Comment: The problem is that the z string value is not known at design time and the number of {} is also not known, so I am looking for a way to evaluate this at run-time.

Comment: @George I updated my answer to show that it works even with dynamic values.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [SmartFormat.NET](https://github.com/scottrippey/SmartFormat.NET), with [named placeholders](https://github.com/scottrippey/SmartFormat.NET/wiki) may be what you are looking for.  You would need to pass in all possible context variables - I don't know of any way to capture the current scope.

```
Dim x As String = "hello"
Dim y As String = "world"
Dim notUsed As String = "Don't care"
Dim z As String = "{x} {y}"
Dim output As String = Smart.Format(z, New With { x, y, notUsed })
Console.WriteLine(output)
```

```
hello world
```

Comment: The issue with this is at design time I don't know how many and the variable names for the {}. All I know is z and z can change at run-time.

Comment: @George You would need to pass in _all possible_ variables, which you should know at design time.  I do not know of any way you can pass in the current scope that would include local variables, although the parameter to `Smart.Format` could be `Me`, which would let you reference any public variables defined at class level.